# nginx returns custom 503 page in base64 encoded string insted of just html

Tags: nginx

i have a strange behavoiur on nginx when i try to implement a custom 503 error page for my maintenance period on nginx.

my custom page is placed on /opt/app_name/maintenance_on.html

my nginx config looks like this:

```
server {
listen 80;

server_name app-name;
root /opt/app_name;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";
proxy_set_header X-Client-IP $remote_addr;
proxy_set_header HTTP_X_FORWARDED_HOST $remote_addr;


access_log  /var/log/nginx/app-name-access.log;
error_log       /var/log/nginx/app-name-error.log;

proxy_buffers   16  64k;
proxy_buffer_size   128k;

proxy_read_timeout 900s;
proxy_connect_timeout 900s;
proxy_send_timeout 900s;


proxy_next_upstream error   timeout invalid_header  http_500    http_502
http_503;

types {
 text/less less;
 text/scss scss;
}

gzip    on;
gzip_min_length 1100;
gzip_buffers    4   32k;
gzip_types  text/css text/less text/plain text/xml application/xml applicatio>
gzip_vary   on;
client_header_buffer_size 4k;
large_client_header_buffers 4 64k;
client_max_body_size 0;

location / {
 if (-f /opt/app_name/maintenance_on.html) {
 return 503;
 }
 proxy_pass    http://127.0.0.1:XXXX;

 proxy_redirect off;
}

location /longpolling {
 proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:XXXX;
}
location ~* .(js|css|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico)$ {
 expires 2d;
 proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:XXXX;
 add_header Cache-Control "public, no-transform";
}

location ~ /[a-zA-Z0-9_-]*/static/ {
 proxy_cache_valid 200 302 60m;
 proxy_cache_valid 404      1m;
 proxy_buffering    on;
 expires 864000;
 proxy_pass    http://127.0.0.1:XXX;
}

error_page 503 @maintenance;
location @maintenance {
 rewrite ^(.*)$ /maintenance_on.html break;
}
}
```

the page looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">
    <title>Performing Maintenance</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        body { text-align: center; padding: 150px; }
        h1 { font-size: 40px; }
        body { font: 20px Helvetica, sans-serif; color: #333; }
        #article { display: block; text-align: left; width: 650px; margin: 0 au>
        a { color: #dc8100; text-decoration: none; }
        a:hover { color: #333; text-decoration: none; }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="article">
    <h1>The system is currently getting some Updates.</h1>
    <div>
        <p>We apologize for the inconvenience, but we're performing some mainte>
        <p>&mdash; Maintainer</p>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

The Problem i face with this configuration is that the nginx redirects to the 503 as expected but the response contains the html page as a base64 encoded string instead of the page as html. So the browser does not show anything.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find a solution although the root cause remains unclear.

## TL;DR

```
  default_type text/html;
```

## Analysis

The only thing changing through these config cases are `add_header` and `default_type` statements.

### Case 1: HTTP 200 works but has duplicated header

HTTP status code 200 seems to make nginx use the given header, although it gets duplicated.

#### Config

```
server {
  listen 443 ssl http2;
  server_name ${SITES};
  ssl_certificate ${CERTLOC}/${SITE}/fullchain.pem;
  ssl_certificate_key ${CERTLOC}/${SITE}/privkey.pem;
  location / {
    add_header Content-Type text/html;
    return 200 '<!DOCTYPE html><html><meta http-equiv="refresh" content="60"><title>Maintenance</title><body><style>body { text-align: center; padding: 150px; font: 20px Helvetica, sans-serif; color: #333; }</style><div><h1>Maintenance ongoing &#x1F477;</h1><p>The page will reload automatically once maintenance has completed, or you can <a href="">click here to reload</a>.</p></div></body></html>';
  }
}
```

#### Response

```
$ curl -I https://maintenance.molnix.com; echo ""; curl https://maintenance.molnix.com; echo ""
HTTP/2 200 
server: nginx
date: Tue, 07 Nov 2023 06:35:46 GMT
content-type: application/octet-stream
content-length: 383
content-type: text/html
    
<!DOCTYPE html><html><meta http-equiv="refresh" content="60"><title>Maintenance</title><body><style>body { text-align: center; padding: 150px; font: 20px Helvetica, sans-serif; color: #333; }</style><div><h1>Maintenance ongoing &#x1F477;</h1><p>The page will reload automatically once maintenance has completed, or you can <a href="">click here to reload</a>.</p></div></body></html>
```

### Case 2: HTTP 503 does not work

Changing HTTP status code to 503 (same with 502, likely others) seems to make nginx omit the content type header and causes browser to rely on the default one being octet-stream.

#### Config

```
server {
  listen 443 ssl http2;
  server_name ${SITES};
  ssl_certificate ${CERTLOC}/${SITE}/fullchain.pem;
  ssl_certificate_key ${CERTLOC}/${SITE}/privkey.pem;
  location / {
    add_header Content-Type text/html;
    return 503 '<!DOCTYPE html><html><meta http-equiv="refresh" content="60"><title>Maintenance</title><body><style>body { text-align: center; padding: 150px; font: 20px Helvetica, sans-serif; color: #333; }</style><div><h1>Maintenance ongoing &#x1F477;</h1><p>The page will reload automatically once maintenance has completed, or you can <a href="">click here to reload</a>.</p></div></body></html>';
  }
}
```

#### Response

```
$ curl -I https://maintenance.molnix.com; echo ""; curl https://maintenance.molnix.com; echo ""
HTTP/2 503 
server: nginx
date: Tue, 07 Nov 2023 06:39:06 GMT
content-type: application/octet-stream
content-length: 383
    
<!DOCTYPE html><html><meta http-equiv="refresh" content="60"><title>Maintenance</title><body><style>body { text-align: center; padding: 150px; font: 20px Helvetica, sans-serif; color: #333; }</style><div><h1>Maintenance ongoing &#x1F477;</h1><p>The page will reload automatically once maintenance has completed, or you can <a href="">click here to reload</a>.</p></div></body></html>
```

### Case 3: HTTP 503 working as expected

Here, just setting the default type causes the seemingly nginx-enforced header itself to be changed and no further settings are needed. Since it is not an add_header statement, it also has the benefit of allowing inheriting other headers which reduces config complexity.

#### Config

```
server {
  listen 443 ssl http2;
  server_name ${SITES};
  ssl_certificate ${CERTLOC}/${SITE}/fullchain.pem;
  ssl_certificate_key ${CERTLOC}/${SITE}/privkey.pem;
  default_type text/html;
  location / {
    return 503 '<!DOCTYPE html><html><meta http-equiv="refresh" content="60"><title>Maintenance</title><body><style>body { text-align: center; padding: 150px; font: 20px Helvetica, sans-serif; color: #333; }</style><div><h1>Maintenance ongoing &#x1F477;</h1><p>The page will reload automatically once maintenance has completed, or you can <a href="">click here to reload</a>.</p></div></body></html>';
  }
}
```

#### Response

```
$ curl -I https://maintenance.molnix.com; echo ""; curl https://maintenance.molnix.com; echo ""
HTTP/2 503 
server: nginx
date: Tue, 07 Nov 2023 06:39:44 GMT
content-type: text/html
content-length: 383
strict-transport-security: max-age=15768000
    
<!DOCTYPE html><html><meta http-equiv="refresh" content="60"><title>Maintenance</title><body><style>body { text-align: center; padding: 150px; font: 20px Helvetica, sans-serif; color: #333; }</style><div><h1>Maintenance ongoing &#x1F477;</h1><p>The page will reload automatically once maintenance has completed, or you can <a href="">click here to reload</a>.</p></div></body></html>
```

#### Notes

- HSTS header in the last response comes from a `conf.d`, and is preserved when not using header statements in this site config. You can ignore that part of the response for the OP case.
- `curl` seems to automatically decode base64 unlike browsers where the response and page are not rendered at all OR browser encode octet streams if they were not already. I did not inspect the raw data stream to confirm as it does not affect the practical implications.
- If you are trying out the configs, replace `${SITES}` with your site such as we used `maintenance.molnix.com`, and `${CERTLOC}/${SITE}` with your certificate path - this one follows Let's Encrypt convention as `/etc/letsencrypt/live` and `maintenance.molnix.com` respectively for the example
- Tested on Ubuntu 22.04 LTS stock packages